# Delete items from woocommerce breadcrumbs

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, breadcrumbs

Right now I have the following structure in the breadcrumbs of woocommerce:

```
HOME / SHOP / MAINCAT / SUBCAT / SUBCAT
```

And what I want is that it looks like this:

```
MAINCAT / SUBCAT / SUBCAT
```

It would remove the link from the home and the woocommerce store page.

Can you help?

Comment: Please share your current code with us. Otherwise there is no way to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function jk_woocommerce_breadcrumbs()
{
    return [
        'delimiter'   => ' &#47; ',
        'wrap_before' => '<nav class="woocommerce-breadcrumb" itemprop="breadcrumb">',
        'wrap_after'  => '</nav>',
        'before'      => '',
        'after'       => '',
        'home'        => _x('', 'breadcrumb', 'woocommerce'),
    ];
}
add_filter('woocommerce_breadcrumb_defaults', 'jk_woocommerce_breadcrumbs');
```

Answer (score 0):

woocommerce->global->breadcrumb.php

```
if(count($breadcrumb)>3){
    $breadcrumb = array_merge(array_slice($breadcrumb, 0, 1, false),array_slice($breadcrumb, -2, 2, false));
}
```